# Broke dryer hose.... need advice

Tags: dryer

Just got a new dryer and the door to my laundry room wouldn’t close due to the dryer so stupid me tried to push my dryer back closer to the wall and in the process I broke the hose and and bent the area on the back of the dryer the hose connects to.

Is this an easy fix and something I can do myself? Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks so much!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can straighten out the dryer tube with just a needle nose pliers. The dryer hose can be trimmed with just a heavy pair of scissors or tin snips if you have a pair.

Many dryers have additional vent exits. Check your owner's manual. Good luck.

Comment: Additional exits?

Comment: Yes.  My dryer, and many I've worked on, has a plate on both rear sides that can be knocked out and the vent pipe ,which comes installed out the back, can be rerouted out either side. You have to get the additional elbow.

Comment: Additional exits, are a brand specific feature and regional specific as well. Most I have seen in Canada and United States don't have that. However, the rest of your advice stands up here. Just posting this to clarify as we don't know where SONGSKIEE is from.

Comment: I’m in the US and I don’t see additional exits on mine. On the back of my dryer, where the hose connects, because I bent that part, can I just bend it back into place? Also, can that part be replaced?

Comment: Yes, just bend it back. It can be replaced, check the parts list in your owners manual or take the part to a home store.